# how to draw dynamic line using shape renderer (Libgdx)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, libgdx, game-development

I am trying to make a matching game using Libgdx. but I stuck in drawing a line from one image to another to match the actors like [this game](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.hegodev.matchit) have . Can anyone help?!!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Since these aren't pixel-width lines, you should either draw solid rectangles with ShapeRenderer, or draw rectangular sprites with SpriteBatch. You just need to work out the math for calculating the rectangle size and orientation based on the two end-points you want to connect.

Answer (score 0):

Use a shape renderer with a rectLine

```
        shapeRenderer.rectLine(new Vector2(x1, y1), new Vector2(x2, y2),lineWidth);
```

where x1, y1 is the position of your first image, and x2 y2 is the position of the second.

If you want the line to follow the users finger as they drag, then you must listen for if the drag/touch event has begun, and then set x2, y2 to the position of the users touch position.